# How to define struct 'Atom' in C? Which is better? Why?

Tags: c, data-structures

ATOM means a pointer, which point to exclusive and constant string.
A string in 'C' should be end with '\0'.

I will show two ways to define an 'ATOM TABLE' structure in 'C':

```
struct atom1 {
    struct atom1 *link;
    int len;
    char *str;
} *bucket[2048]
```

and

```
struct atom2 {
    struct atom2 *link;
    int len;
    char str[1];
} *bucket[2048]
```

So, when I want to allocate memory for these two type of ATOM, I also have two ways.

```
// memory + 1 for '\0'
struct atom1 *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + len + 1);
```

and

```
// memory for '\0' is already in the define of struct atom
struct atom2 *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + len);
```

So we can see, when we want to allocate memory, **'atom2'** looks better. But on the other side, if we want to access the memory of the string, we will break the rule of 'C', because **'char str[1];'** in **'atom2'**.

**Is 'atom2' really good?**

Comment: In none of the cases you should cast the return of `malloc` and also it is less error prone if you'd use `sizeof *p` instead of using the type name. Also I suppose that you are aware that for the first method you'd still have to assign the tail of your allocation to `p->str` somehow.

Comment: @JensGustedt can you tell me why use 'sizeof *p' is better? Thanks so much.

Comment: Because it avoids redundancy. If some day you decide to change the type on the left, your size expression in the call to `malloc` is still valid.

Comment: Just a general tip : it would be increadibly difficult in the future if you are building a large cheminformatics system since there are abstractions which are hard to implement in C :) cheminformatics engineer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atom1 doesn't make any sense, because you should allocate memory dynamically for what `str` points at, not for the whole struct. As the code currently stands, there is no sound way in which you will be able to use atom1.

atom2 invokes undefined behavior. This was known as the "struct hack" in the old C standard, and was never guaranteed to work. Writing out of bounds of the fixed array is not allowed, even though you may have allocated data at the end of the struct. Because you don't know where the struct ends: it could have padding bytes.

> Is 'atom2' really good?

Neither method is good, don't use either of them. In modern C, you can do this in a safe manner, by using a flexible array member:

```
typedef struct atom3 
{
  struct atom3* link;
  size_t        lenght;
  char          str[];
} atom3_t;
```

And then allocate memory as:

```
atom3_t* p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + length + 1);
```

After that, you can safely use `str` as if it was any array with size `length + 1`.

Comment: "As the code currently stands, there is no sound way in which you will be able to use atom1" - sure there is; just allocate the storage for the string separately.

Comment: @davmac If the string is allocated separately, then explain to me how `malloc(sizeof(struct atom1) + len + 1);` makes any sense.

Comment: that allocation doesn't make sense. But that is not the same as "no sound way to use atom1".

Comment: I know we can use 'char str[];', but it seems like a better define for 'atom1'. Can you explain why define 'char str[1];' in struct is not good? Thanks.

Comment: @sunnyleevip What part of the explanation is it that you don't understand? Do you know about alignment and struct padding?

Answer (score 5):

Since C99 you have the option of using *flexible array members* - that is, the same as your `atom2` but without the array size specified:

```
struct atom2 {
    struct atom2 *link;
    int len;
    char str[];
} *bucket[2048];
```

This way you get the benefit of being able to allocate the string and structure together, without violating language rules.

In this case when you allocate memory, be sure to account for the nul string terminator:

```
struct atom2 *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + len + 1);
```

(Note also you do not ever need to cast the result of `malloc`).

Note that your `atom1` structure contains a `char *` which is semantically different to a `char []`. The pointer is a data member which occupies storage and which can be made to point anywhere, whereas the flexible array member does not occupy any storage (other than what you allocate for it explicitly) and always trails the rest of the object. To use `atom1` you'd need to allocate storage for the struct object and the string separately:

```
struct atom1 *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
p->str = malloc(len + 1);
```

The allocation you suggested in your question:

```
struct atom1 *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + len + 1);
```

... would at least require that you set up the pointer, `p->str`, to point at the correct place (something like `p->str = ((char *) p) + sizeof(*p)`) but I'm not certain that you wouldn't be invoking undefined behaviour if you tried to store the string at that location.

Comment: I know we can use 'char str[];', but it seems like a better define for 'atom1'. Can you explain why define 'char str[1];' in struct is not good? Thanks.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread your comment. `str[1]` is not good in the struct because it doesn't allow you to access the string beyond the first character, seeing as you are exceeding the array bounds and that results in undefined behaviour. Your question implies that you understood this already though, so I'm not sure why you are asking.